# flyout should not hide when the user taps/clicks in metro app

Tags: html, windows-8, winjs

In my metro style app (windows 8) I have created an page overlay and a flyout displaying an message. When the user clicks on the page the flyout message goes to hidden. But I want flyout to remain even when the user clicks on the overlay page. I am using HTML5 and WinJS.
Is there anyway I can achieve the above scenario using someother control or can I prevent the page to stop reacting to events when the user taps/clicks on the screen.

Comment: The Flyout is not sticky/modal by design, as @Dominic Hopton notes.

I would recommend against trying to work around this, as by fighting the design of the app environment, you increase the likelihood of your users encountering unexpected behavior. What is this message used for, that you want it to remain on-screen?

Answer (score 5):

This is not really supported -- the Flyout itself doesn't have the concept of being persistent/sticky/modal. If you look at the code in base.js, you'll see that it doesn't expose any code to leverage the inbuilt sticky behavior that is used in the appbar (which is kinda of flyout, it turns out.

There are a couple things you can do:

- Pass "`_sticky: true`" to the constructor of the flyout. e.g `<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout" data-win-options="{ _sticky: true}">`
- Attach a click handler to the top of the document, and if it's on the click eating div that the flyout creates, cancel the event
- Create your own UI by simply adding a new div to the body, and absolute positioning it.

Comment: the sticky trick does not seems to work. does it have to be used together with the click handler?

Comment: data-win-options="{ _sticky: true} works perfectly for me. thanks so much